# Populate GridLayout with Repeater

Tags: qt, qml, repeater, qtquick2

I try to add cells to my `GridLayout` by using a `Repeater`. My data is stored in a model and containing two properties per element:

- `Title`
- `Value`

My goal is to get a `GridLayout` containing the `Title` in first cell and the `Value` in the second cell of each row.

```
GridLayout {
    id: someId
    columns: 2
    rowSpacing: 5
    columnSpacing: 5
    anchors.margins: 5
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right

    Repeater {
        model: myModel
        Label {
            text: modelData.title
        }
        TextArea {
            text: modelData.value
        }
    }
}
```

But QML `Repeater` allows only one element. Any ideas how I could get the layout I want?

```
+------------+---------------------------------------+
|            |                                       |
|  title0    |         value0                        |
|            |                                       |
|            |                                       |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
|            |                                       |
|            |                                       |
|  title1    |         value1                        |
|            |                                       |
|            |                                       |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
|            |                                       |
|  title2    |         value2                        |
|            |                                       |
|            |                                       |
+------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply use two `Repeater`s within a `GridLayout`, as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    width: 600; height: 400; visible: true

    GridLayout {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2
        rowSpacing: 5
        columnSpacing: 5
        anchors.margins: 5
        // example models
        property var titles: [ "title1", "title2", "title3", "title4", "title5" ]
        property var values: [ "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5" ]

        Repeater {
            model: grid.titles
            Label {
                Layout.row: index
                Layout.column: 0
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                text: modelData
            }
        }

        Repeater {
            model: grid.values
            TextArea {
                Layout.row: index
                Layout.column: 1
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                text: modelData
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `index` parameter is freely available and store the current row of the model.

By using the `Layout.fillWidth` attached property you can control the `width` of the single column.

Of course, each cell that belongs to a column has the same size of all the other cells of that column, unlike what happens using two `Column` components.

This solution has a few drawbacks, but it's good if your purpose is mainly to print plain data from a model.

Comment: just care i run in to a bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65121, if it doesn't work for you, you can always the combination of a row with 2 column inside

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`GridLayout.flow`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-layouts-gridlayout.html#flow-prop) to specify in which order the cells should be filled, i.e. row- (`GridLayout.LeftToRight`) or column-wise (`GridLayout.TopToBottom`). Note that you should specify the [number of rows](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-layouts-gridlayout.html#rows-prop) when using `GridLayout.TopToBottom`.

Using this solution, the (simplified) example of skypjack would become:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    width: 600; height: 400; visible: true

    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        // specify the flow and number of rows
        flow: GridLayout.TopToBottom
        rows: repeater.count

        Repeater {
            id: repeater
            model: [ "title1", "title2", "title3", "title4", "title5", "title6" ] // example model
            Label {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                text: modelData
            }
        }

        Repeater {
            model: [ "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6" ]  // example model
            TextArea {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                text: modelData
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The model-view principle assumes that each model node displays by different delegate component object. So I advice you to listen to @BaCaRoZzo's comment and do that with `Column` instead of `GridLayout`. Sure, QML is very flexible and you can do something like that:

```js
Component {
    id: labelDelegate
    Label { text: myList.get(_index / 2).title }
}

Component {
    id: textAreaDelegate
    TextArea { text: myList.get(_index / 2).value }
}

ListModel {
    id: myList
    ListElement {title: "title1"; value: "value1"}
    ListElement {title: "title2"; value: "value2"}
    ListElement {title: "title3"; value: "value3"}
}

GridLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    columns: 2
    Repeater {
        model: myList.count * 2
        delegate: Loader {
            property int _index: index
            sourceComponent: {
                if(index % 2)
                    return textAreaDelegate;
                else
                    return labelDelegate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but that's too weird to use it in real project.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try the column-based solution as suggested by @BaCaRoZzo. Even I'm not sure if the result is what i want. I think the first cell of each row will have a different width. Lets see if I'm wrong (hope so ^^ )

Comment: The suggested version to populate the Columns work pretty good, but the resulting Layout isn't what I want. The first Cell of each row has a different width. So this is not really a solution for problem. I'll try the wired solution of @folibis ... if it works it isn't wired enough :)

Comment: Naaah, don't use it, I've posted it as example of how you should not do. So, in case of using `Column` you can set same width for every `Label`. Or, more correctly, you should review the model.

Answer (score 1):

Nest as many elements as you want inside an Item in the Repeater's delegate and re-parent them to the GridLayout when the Item completes.

```
GridLayout {
    id: grid
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    columns: 2
    rowSpacing: 5
    columnSpacing: 5
    anchors.margins: 5

    Repeater {
        model: [
            { title: "title1 that's long", value: "value1" },
            { title: "title2 medium",      value: "value2" },
            { title: "title3",             value: "value3" }
        ]
        delegate: Item {
            Component.onCompleted: {
                while (children.length) { children[0].parent = grid; }
            }

            Label {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
                color: "gray"
                text: modelData.title
            }
            TextArea {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                font.bold: true
                text: modelData.value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of running QML code]