# QML Repeater and QML Grid Layout with variable number of columns

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have an model that consist of objects with some properties, e.g.:

```
ListModel {
    id: fruitModel

    ListElement {
        name: "Apple"
        color: "green"
        cost: 2.45
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Orange"
        color: "orange"
        cost: 3.25
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Banana"
        color: "yellow"
        cost: 1.95
    }
}
```

And now I want to display this model using `GridLayout`. For each property I want to use one element inside `GridLayout`, e.g:

```
GridLayout {
    columns: 3

    Text { text: "Apple" }
    Rectangle { color: "green" }
    SpinBox { value: 2.45 }

    Text { text: "Orange" }
    Rectangle { color: "orange" }
    SpinBox { value: 3.25 }

    Text { text: "Banana" }
    Rectangle { color: "yellow" }
    SpinBox { value: 1.95 }
}
```

The point is that I can easily change the `columns` property of `GridLayout` and make my layout narrower (e.g. to fit small screens). I can use Repeater to fill `GridLayout`. However such approach will fill my `GridLayout` in wrong order:

```
GridLayout {
    columns: 3

    Repeater {
        model: fruitModel
        Text { text: name }
    }

    Repeater {
        model: fruitModel
        Rectangle { color: color }
    }

    Repeater {
        model: fruitModel
        SpinBox { value: value }
    }
}
```

And it is waste to use `Layout.column` and `Layout.row` attached properties since I want to easily change number of columns in `GridLayout`.

Is there any way to fill `GridLayout` with data from model row by row?

**UPD1:**

Behaviour that I want to get:

[image]

```
GridLayout {
    columns: parent.width > 235 ? 3 : 1

    Text { text: "Apple" }
    Rectangle { color: "green"; width: 40; height: 40 }
    SpinBox { value: 2 }

    Text { text: "Orange" }
    Rectangle { color: "orange"; width: 40; height: 40 }
    SpinBox { value: 3 }

    Text { text: "Banana" }
    Rectangle { color: "yellow"; width: 40; height: 40 }
    SpinBox { value: 1 }
}
```

**UPD2:**
Modified variant from @m7913d:

```
GridLayout {
    id: layout
    property int maxColumns: 3
    columns: parent.width > 235 ? maxColumns : 1

    Repeater {
        model: fruitModel
        Text {
            text: name
            Layout.row: layout.columns == maxColumns ? index : (maxColumns * index)
            Layout.column: 0
        }
    }

    Repeater {
        model: fruitModel
        Rectangle {
            Layout.preferredWidth: 30
            Layout.preferredHeight: 30
            color: col
            Layout.row: layout.columns == maxColumns ? index : (maxColumns * index + 1)
            Layout.column: layout.columns == maxColumns ? 1 : 0
        }
    }

    Repeater {
        model: fruitModel
        SpinBox {
            value: val
            Layout.row: layout.columns == maxColumns ? index : (maxColumns * index + 2)
            Layout.column: layout.columns == maxColumns ? 2 : 0
        }
    }
}
```

It's working but not easy-to-modify solution plus sometimes during layout resize there is messages `QGridLayoutEngine::addItem: Cell (1, 0) already taken`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate GridLayout with Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969414/populate-gridlayout-with-repeater)

Comment: Unfortunately solution in "Populate GridLayout with Repeater" uses `Layout.column` and `Layout.row` attached properties, so it is impossible to change `columns` property of GridLayout dynamically.

Comment: You could show a diagram or image of what you want to obtain

Comment: @KamilZaripov , Have you investigated [`Flow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flow.html)?  This may give you the responsive layout you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, maybe it will be helpful, but how to populate `Flow` with items from model?

Comment: @KamilZaripov: You populate it just the same way as you do with a `Grid[Layout]` - you use a `Repeater`. I however would use a `Column` and populate that with a fitting delegate: When wide enough, a `Row[Layout]`, if narrower a `Column[Layout]` or some `Item` with freely arranged children. With this you would have maximum versatility.

Comment: The reason, why you could not easily change the number of columns when using `Layout.column` and `Layout.row` would be something you should elaborate on. On first glance I can't see any reason for that.

Comment: @derM can you write some simple example?

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach is to extend [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32985288/7621674) with condition column/row indexes:

```
GridLayout {
    id:gridLayout
    columns: parent.width > 235 ? 3 : 1

    Repeater {
        model: fruitModel
        implicitHeight: 50
        Text {
            text: name
            Layout.row: gridLayout.columns == 3 ? index : 3 * index
            Layout.column: 0
        }
    }

    Repeater {
        model: fruitModel
        Rectangle {
            color: model.color
            implicitWidth: 50
            implicitHeight: 50
            Layout.row: gridLayout.columns == 3 ? index : 3 * index + 1
            Layout.column: gridLayout.columns == 3 ? 1 : 0
        }
    }

    Repeater {
        model: fruitModel
        SpinBox {
            value: value
            Layout.row: gridLayout.columns == 3 ? index : 3 * index + 2
            Layout.column: gridLayout.columns == 3 ? 2 : 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this approach and after some modification it works, but it looks little bit ugly and sometimes it writes into output `QGridLayoutEngine::addItem: Cell (1, 0) already taken` and so on.

Comment: @KamilZaripov: Please either edit this answer, or post an answer yourself. The Question-part is no place for answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `Column` filled by either `Row`s or `Column`s (or any other arrangement) as delegates.

```
Column {
    id: rootCol
    anchors.fill: parent
    Repeater {
        model: fruitModel
        delegate: rootCol.width > 300 ? rowDel : colDel
    }

    Component {
        id: rowDel
        Row {
            Text { width: 100; height: 50; text: model.name }
            Rectangle { width: 50; height: 50; color: model.color }
            SpinBox { width: 150; height: 50; value: model.cost }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: colDel
        Column {
            Text { width: 100; height: 50; text: model.name }
            Rectangle { width: 50; height: 50; color: model.color }
            SpinBox { width: 150; height: 50; value: model.cost}
        }
    }
}
```

Or maybe:

```
Column {
    id: rootCol
    anchors.fill: parent
    Repeater {
        model: fruitModel
        delegate: Flow {
            anchors {
                left: parent.left
                right: parent.right
            }

            Text { width: 100; height: 50; text: model.name }
            Rectangle { width: 50; height: 50; color: model.color }
            SpinBox { width: 150; height: 50; value: model.value }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but in this case it isn't `GridLayout` it is `RowLayout` inside of `ColumnLayout`. There is a difference. In `GridLayout` all items in same column has same width but in `RowLayout` inside of `ColumnLayout` they don't.

Comment: With a little work, you can implement that behavior yourself. `GridLayout` is not doing magic.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is possible to do it without `GridLayout`, moreover currently I'm using  `RowLayout` inside of `ColumnLayout` and I manually set same width for `Item`s in same column. But it isn't very convenient approach and I'm just wondering is there an easier way. Evidently there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another solution:

> The Idea: **add the children in the right order**

For that we will need to make sure that all `Item`s for a model entry.

```
GridLayout {
    id: gl
    columns: parent.width > 235 ? 3 : 1
}
Instantiator {
    model: fruitModel
    delegate: QtObject {
        property Item text: Text { parent: gl; text: model.name }
        property Item rect: Rectangle { parent: gl; color: model.color; width: 50; height: 50; }
        property Item spin: SpinBox { parent: gl; value: model.cost; }
    }
}
```

> **Note:** This will fail when entries in the model will be inserted or reordered, as in this solution the entries are always appended.
>   Other than that, it will automatically support column changes