# Using GridLayout with QAbstractModelList and Repeaters

Tags: qml, repeater, qt-quick

I have following problem in QtQuick (QML). I want to display a table with data from QAbstractListModel in a table layout. I use GridlĹayout and repeaters for it:

```
  ScrollView {
        id: scrollView
        width: parent.width
        anchors.fill: parent
        clip: true
        ScrollBar.horizontal.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn

        Repeater{
            model: _network.qqjourneyslist.length
            Item {
                GridLayout {
                    id: inr
                    columns: 5
                    width: rect2.width
                    layoutDirection: "RightToLeft"
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.top: parent.bottom

                    Repeater{
                        model: _network.qqjourneyslist[index]
                        Item {
                            Text{
                                id:t1
                                //width: 100
                                text: model.startstop
                                //Layout.fillWidth: true

                            }
                            Text{
                                id:t2
                                //width: 100

                                text: model.starttime
                                //Layout.fillWidth: true
                                //anchors.left: t1.right
                            }
                            Text{
                                id:t3
                                //width: 100
                                text: model.lineno
                                //Layout.fillWidth: true
                                //anchors.left: t2.right
                            }
                            Text{
                                id: t4
                                //width: 100
                                text: model.endstop
                                // Layout.fillWidth: true
                                //anchors.left: t3.right
                            }
                            Text{
                                id: t5
                                //width: 100
                                text: model.endtime
                                //Layout.fillWidth: true
                                //anchors.left: t4.right
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, that when I insert a repeater in the GridLayout the flow is destroyed and the Texts are overwriting each other. I tried a lot of things like insert width for the texts or use Layout.row, Layout.columns, but nothing works.
I also looked at [Populate GridLayout with Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969414/populate-gridlayout-with-repeater) but this topic did not help in my case or at least I did not find a way how to modify it for my purpose. _network.qqjourneislist is a QList wiht QAbstractListModel which I would like to use and outside of the Layout there are working fine.
Could you please help me how to use a repeater and QAbstractListModel?
I do not keen on using GridLayout I just want to create a table with row and columns for my model. I know there are lot of another table objects but I do not know which to use and trying all out is a long way for me.
I am glad of every advice I receive and thank you for it!

EDIT....

The solution with ColumnLayout and RowLayout is working until I use a Repeater in a Repeater which yields to that the text lines are not produced.

The code is following:

```
 ColumnLayout {
            id: inr
           // anchors.fill: parent
            width: parent.width
            layoutDirection: "LeftToRight"
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.margins: 15
            //anchors.horizontalCenter: parent
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
    Repeater{
        model: _network.qqjourneyslist.length

   Repeater{
       id: rep1
        model: _network.qqjourneyslist[index]
            //width: inr.width
            //height: 50
            RowLayout{
                height: 20
                Layout.preferredHeight: 20
                spacing: 10
                    Text{
                        id:t1
                        width: wind.implicitWidth/3
                        //anchors.left: parent.left
                        //anchors.top: parent.top
                    text: model.startstop
                    font.pointSize: 12
                    Layout.preferredWidth: wind.implicitWidth/3

                    }

            Text{
                id:t2
                //width: 100

            text: model.starttime
            font.pointSize: 12
            font.bold: true
            //Layout.fillWidth: true
            //anchors.left: t1.right
            }
            Text{
                id:t3
                //width: 100
            text: model.lineno
            font.pointSize: 12
            color: "red"
            //Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            //Layout.preferredWidth: parent.implicitWidth/3
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
            Text{
                x:wind.implicitWidth/12*9
                id: t4

            text: model.endstop
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
            font.pointSize: 12
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.implicitWidth/3
            //anchors.left: t3.right
            }
            Text{
                id: t5
                //width: 100
            text: model.endtime
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
            font.pointSize: 12
            font.bold: true
            //Layout.fillWidth: true
            //anchors.left: t4.right
            }
            }

            }
   RowLayout{
       height: 12
       //Layout.preferredHeight: 12
       //anchors.top: rep1.bottom
       Rectangle{
           //width: parent.width
           //Layout.
           Layout.row: 3*index
           Layout.preferredHeight: 12
           Layout.fillWidth: true
           color: "grey"
           //Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
           //Layout.fillWidth: parent
           //Layout.alignment: Qt.Right
           radius: 5
       }
        }}}
```

I want to produce something like that (the lower rectangle)

[right version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlTEh.png)

but I get only the rectangles and no text. If I remove the last RowLayout then the texrows are displayed properly.

[something is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BxM6.png)

The _network.qqjournieslist is a QList of QObejcts* - QAbstractListModel - so it should be possible to assign it to model.
Thanks for every help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `Text` objects overwrite themselves because their parent is an `Item`, which doesn't tell them where to be positioned. You don't really describe how you want the output to look, so I'll make an assumption that you want those 5 text strings to appear as a single row in your grid. Then you can just use a `Column` with a `Row`, (or a `ColumnLayout` with a `RowLayout` if you prefer).

```
Column {
    Row {
        Repeater {
            model: _network.qqjourneyslist
            Text {
                width: 100 // Column 1 width
                text: model.startstop
            }
            Text {
                width: 100 // Column 2 width
                text: model.starttime
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT:

Your updated code doesn't work because you seem to misunderstand how `Repeaters` work. The model of a `Repeater` can either be a count of how many times it should repeat, or a list of some sort that tells the `Repeater` how many items to create.

Your first `Repeater` uses the length of your list as a model, which is ok. Let's say its value is 10. That means it will create 10 of whatever is inside it. And what's inside that `Repeater`? Another `Repeater`. The model of that second `Repeater` though is the contents of a single item in your list. That's a problem. Unless that item is also a list of some sort, the `Repeater` won't know how to use it as a count. That's why in my code above, I changed your example to only use a single `Repeater`. That's all that's needed for your case. The model for each row needs to be repeated, but not your columns.

Comment: but if the text's are not the same, they will take up a different amount of space, right? I think the poster wants a tabular view, where all the item are nicely lined up below each other

Comment: You can specify width for each `Text` object.

Comment: True, but not so nice if you want to have the app in multiple resolutions

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't listed as a requirement. Using `RowLayout` could fix that.

Comment: I supposed to use the grid layout for making grids, does it mean that for tables where are repatears I cant use Grids or GridLayouts? Your sollution works but I thought there is a more elegant why how to do this.

Comment: @FrantišekPrinz, no it doesn't mean you can't use a `GridLayout`. I just don't find it "more elegant" to do it that way. I think the code I've provided is pretty straightforward and readable, which meets my subjective definition of "elegant".

Comment: @JarMan Thanks, but I am not sure if I understand correctly what do you mean. But __network.qqjourneyslist is indeed a QList of QAbstractItemModel so the Items should be compatible with model in Repeater I think. Parcularly when I remove the last RowLayout which is included only in the outer Repeater it works perfectly. So Repeater in a Repeater is possible or should I avoid it?

Comment: Yes, `__network.qqjourneyslist` is a list, but `__network.qqjourneyslist[index]` is not, and that's what you're using for your second `Repeater`. A `Repeater` in a `Repeater` is not needed for the way your data is structured.

Comment: But I have in the `QAbstractItemModel` more objects of starttime, endtime etc. so the inner `Repeater` produces more than one `RowLayout` and I need the `Rectangle` after the last item so how can I do it?

Comment: This is pointless to continue when you haven't even shown what your model actually looks like. I've already spent too much time on this (and received a downvote for my effort).